# First try at lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I tried to make my first lambda example but I can't get this simple code to work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Lambda {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] names = {"Wim", "Kian", "Dirk", "Emmanuel", "Frank", "Michaël", "Anna", "Damien", "Alberto"};
        final String[] filteredNames = getNamesWithCriteria(names, (String s) -> s.startsWith("A"));
}

    private String[] getNamesWithCriteria(final String[] names, Predicate<String> predicate) {
        final ArrayList<String> filteredNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String name : names) {
            if(predicate.test(name)) {
                filteredNames.add(name);
            }
        }
        return (String[]) filteredNames.toArray();
    }

}
```

These are the errors that I get:

```
Lambda.java:8: error: ')' expected
        final String[] filteredNames = getNamesWithCriteria(names, (String s) ->
 s.startsWith("A"));
                                                                          ^
Lambda.java:8: error: illegal start of expression
        final String[] filteredNames = getNamesWithCriteria(names, (String s) ->
 s.startsWith("A"));
                                                                               ^

Lambda.java:8: error: ';' expected
        final String[] filteredNames = getNamesWithCriteria(names, (String s) ->
 s.startsWith("A"));
```

Comment: A you sure you are compiling your code in Java 8?

Comment: You might be running JDK 8, but I bet the source level is set pre-8. Set `javac -source 1.8 -target 1.8`. It now expects the end of a cast `(String)`.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you're not probably compiling your code in Java 8, you're also calling non-static method getNamesWithCriteria from static context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using Java 8 in your project. It compiled fine here in Java 8. However you have a bug in this line:

```
return (String[]) filteredNames.toArray();
```

If you wanted to return an array, change the return statement to this.

```
return filteredNames.toArray(new String[filteredNames.size()]);
```

Comment: Ok strange. I did java -version and it said 1.8. But when I do javac -version it says 1.7. How is that possible?

Comment: Have you got two JDKs installed?

Comment: Ok this is why: H:\>where java
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\ibm_sdk70\bin\java.exe

H:\>where javac
C:\Program Files\Java\ibm_sdk70\bin\javac.exe

Answer (score 2):

Here's code that works when compiled with Java 8. Note that all your errors are not related to Java 8 features :

```
public class Lambda {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] names = {"Wim", "Kian", "Dirk", "Emmanuel", "Frank", "Michael", "Anna", "Damien", "Alberto"};
        final String[] filteredNames = getNamesWithCriteria(names, (String s) -> s.startsWith("A"));

    }

    // changed method to be static
    private static String[] getNamesWithCriteria(final String[] names, Predicate<String> predicate) {
        final ArrayList<String> filteredNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String name : names) {
            if(predicate.test(name)) {
                filteredNames.add(name);
            }
        }
        // proper conversion to String[]
        return  filteredNames.toArray(new String[filteredNames.size()]);
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks. The biggest problem was having multiple JDK's.